# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am getting the following error when I use Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error xml2json.js:1
SyntaxError: syntax error ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js:1
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap
minErr/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:63:5
module/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:1769:1
ensure@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:1691:5
module@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:1765:7
loadModules/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4097:11
forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:323:11
loadModules@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js:4081:5
loadModules/<@h
```

Here are my code imports:

```
<head>
    <title>Automation Downloads</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-cookies.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets/js/xml2json.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <script src="default.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize' , 'ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $cookieStore){
    // all code goes here
});
```

Can anybody help me out? I'm also interested in knowing what is causing the SyntaxError errors. None of these issues come up in Chrome. I've also tried all the solutions others on SO have given and none of them worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add ui.bootstrap.js file in your head tag and see if it is working or not

```
<head>
    <title>Automation Downloads</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-cookies.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets/js/xml2json.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap‌​.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <script src="default.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
```

Comment: @jbn134 ok..so can you please try by upgrading your angular js version to 1.4.0 ?

Comment: I can but AngularJS 1.4.x is not supported by Angular-UI... So that wouldn't work.

Comment: actually  I am using angular version 1.4.0 along with ui-bootstrap and is working fine

Comment: Ok. Just tried Version 1.4.0 and it still doesn't work. However, when I load another random page with AngularJS on it, and come back to this webpage, it WORKS! I have no idea why it works, it just does. Any clues?

Comment: Will u be able to provide plunker ??

Comment: Sorry can't really do that. Content is proprietary.